# How to access a form control for another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have two `Form` classes, one of which has a `ListBox`. I need a setter for the `SelectedIndex` property of the `ListBox`, which I want to call from the second `Form`.

At the moment I am doing the following:

**Form 1**

```
public int MyListBoxSelectedIndex
{
     set { lsbMyList.SelectedIndex = value; }
}
```

**Form 2**

```
private ControlForm mainForm; // form 1

public AddNewObjForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     mainForm = new ControlForm();           
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
     mainForm.MyListBoxSelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Making them Singleton is not a completely bad idea, but personally I would not prefer to do it that way. I'd rather pass the reference of one to another form. Here's an example.

Form1 triggers Form2 to open. Form2 has overloaded constructor which takes calling form as argument and provides its reference to Form2 members. This solves the communication problem. For example I've exposed Label Property as public in Form1 which is modified in Form2.

With this approach you can do communication in different ways.

**[Download Link for Sample Project](http://demo.ruchitsurati.net/files/FormsCommunication.zip)**

//**Your Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return Lbl.Text; }
        set { Lbl.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

//**Your Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form1 mainForm = null;
    public Form2(Form callingForm)
    {
        mainForm = callingForm as Form1; 
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mainForm.LabelText = txtMessage.Text;
    }
}
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [ruchitsurati.net](http://demo.ruchitsurati.net/files/frm1.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [ruchitsurati.net](http://demo.ruchitsurati.net/files/frm2.png))</sub>

Comment: Hello, guys! Should the "private Form1 mainForm = null;" give you errors, just change the "null" to "new mainForm();"

Worked for me.

Comment: private Form1? mainForm = null;

Answer (score 6):

Access the form's controls like this:

```
formname.controls[Index]
```

You can cast as appropriate control type, Example:

```
DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView) formname.Controls[Index];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way, in case you don't want to loop through "ALL" controls like Joe Dabones suggested.
Make a function in Form2 and call it from Form1.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetIndex(int value)
    {
        lsbMyList.SelectedIndex = value;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form2 frm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm=new Form2();
        frm.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm.SetIndex(Int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**If `ChildForm` wants to access the `ParentForm`**

Pass `ParentForm` instance to the `ChildForm` constructor.

```
public partial class ParentForm: Form
{
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ParentProperty{get;set;}

    private void CreateChild()
    {
         var childForm = new ChildForm(this);
         childForm.Show();
    }
}

public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    private ParentForm parentForm;

    public ChildForm(ParentForm parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        parentForm = parent;
        parentForm.ParentProperty = "Value from Child";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the Singleton Design Pattern for something like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern . I'll make the main form that the application is running under the singleton, and then create accessors to forms and controls I want to touch in other areas. The other forms can then either get a pointer to the control they want to modify, or the data in the main part of the application they wish to change.

Another approach is to setup events on the different forms for communicating, and use the main form as a hub of sorts to pass the event messages from one form to another within the application.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use events?  This is what they are for, communication between objects without tight coupling.

Comment: @Ed Swangren - That's why I suggested them as well. It's totally an option, though it requires a whole lot more time to do each individual event as you want to add new hooks, while a singleton is pretty much a one time thing. My personal favorite thing to do is to abstract the UI out from the core behavior of the application. That core then is the singleton, and can have events attached to it. Then all UI is just a view of the data within the core. This makes doing undo/redo behaviors much much easier.

Comment: I don't see any requirement for undo-redo behavior, and I disagree with your statement that implies that seting up events is an onerous task. Singletons are often a crappy solution to any problem.  I was going to list some supporting arguments, bit I found a pretty good list here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, first you can access the other form like this:
(let's say your other form is `Form2`)

```
//in Form 1
Form2 F2 = new Form2();
foreach (Control c in F2.Controls)
         if(c.Name == "TextBox1")
            c.Text = "hello from Form1";
```

That's it, you just write in `TextBox1` in `Form2` from `Form1`.

Comment: Form2 F2 = new Form2(); this will cause a new instance of the form, any change you may create will be applied to that new instance instead of the "other" visible form.

Answer (score 0):

Here's also another example that does "Find and Highlight". There's a second form (a modal) that opens and contains a textbox to enter some text and then our program finds and highlights the searched text in the RichTextBox (in the calling form). **In order to select the RichTextBox element in the calling form, we can use the `.Controls.OfType<T>()` method:**

```cs
private void findHltBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var StrBox = _callingForm.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>().First(ctrl => ctrl.Name == "richTextBox1");
    StrBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;

    var SearchStr = findTxtBox.Text;
    int SearchStrLoc = StrBox.Find(SearchStr);

    StrBox.Select(SearchStrLoc, SearchStr.Length);
    StrBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Also in the same class (modal's form), to access the calling form use the technique mentioned in the @CuiousGeek's answer:

```cs
public partial class FindHltModalForm : Form
{
        private Form2 _callingForm = null;
        public FindHltModalForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public FindHltModalForm(Form2 CallingForm)
    {
        _callingForm = CallingForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
//...
```