# How to assign label texts based off of global values on another form

Tags: visual-studio

My program has two forms. I'm trying to define the global value, "Name" on one form based on what is entered in to that text box. I then assign that to Name and when the other form is opened I am attempting to have it update to the variable "LabelName" On the other form. I am getting the error that "Value of type 'string' cannot be converted to 'Label'. Can't seem to figure out why

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Are you trying this with Winforms? WPF? Xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the change of label from another class by making the label public and accessing it from wherever you want...
But hear seems like you have a problem in assigning a value to the text property.
do you sure you did it correct?
example :-
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text();

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

Try This : 
[How to access a form control for another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822980/how-to-access-a-form-control-for-another-form)

And also it looks like you are trying to assign the string value to the **Label itself** and that gives the above error. Assign the string to the **label.Text** instead.