# Data not getting entered to listview

Tags: c#

Im trying to add data to a listview from another form. I have tired doing it from the same form and that works like it should, but when I try to pass the info between the forms no data gets entered.

**Form 1** Contains listview

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newTask form = new newTask();
        form.Show();
    }
```

**Form 2** Contains form to submit info to listview

```
         public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string url = textBox1.Text;
        string size = textBox2.Text;

        Form1 table = new Form1();

        table.listView1.Items.Add(url);
        table.listView1.Items.Add(size);


        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the items on an _existing instance_ of the form? Note that you're currently adding the items to the ListView on a _new instance_ of `Form1` which (at least in the code block above) not yet displayed.

Comment: Yeah its an existing instace.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. You're adding the items to a completely different (not shown) instance. You need to show us how the _existing instance_ of the form is created so we can help you access it instead. If `Form1` is the main form, then you should show how the _current_ form is created. Please [edit] your question and add the relevant information.

Comment: `table` is not the same form that has already been opened because you just did `new Form1()`. This continues to be one of the most asked .net questions on SO. Forms are just regular classes so how would you set values on an instance of a class?  You would not make a new instance, you would set the values on the existing one.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, pretty new to programing. The listview is loaded on the main interface of the application. There is a button which opens up a new form that has couple of text inputs. The code above is the code thats gets ran when I hit the submit button.

Comment: Add the following to the code you have shown and it may become clear: `table.ShowDialog()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a form control for another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822980/how-to-access-a-form-control-for-another-form)

Comment: If you're using `ShowDialog()` to open the second form, use `ShowDialog(this)` instead so that in the second form you can access the main one by using something like `var table = (Form1)this.Owner;`. If, one the other hand, you are using `.Show()` to open the second form, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4823535/4934172) should help you.

Comment: You should use the Delegates and Callback technique to Send data from one Form to Another

Answer (score 0):

With `Form1 table = new Form1();` you are creating new object type `Form1` and it doesn't reference to your old form.

What you need to do is change constructor of second form to

```
private Form1 myFirstForm;

public newTask(Form1 form1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myFirstForm = form1;
}
```

and your second part of code should then look like this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string url = textBox1.Text;
    string size = textBox2.Text;

    myFirstForm.listView1.Items.Add(url);
    myFirstForm.listView1.Items.Add(size);

    this.Hide();
}
```