# How to change image of a picturebox from another form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I change the image of a form PictureBox, from another form?
Example. Form2 image needs to change Form1 image.

I tried this.

```
    exmp.Code 1        

    //This is for Form1
    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Fr2 = new Form2();
        Fr2.Owner = this;
    }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Fr2.Show();
    }

    //This is for Form2
        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox2.Image;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

This code doesn't work!
But if I try this it will work.

```
    exmp.Code 1        

    //Form1
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Fr2 = new Form2();
        Fr2.Show();
        Fr2.Owner = this;
    }
    
    //Form2 
    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            (this.Owner as Form1).pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox2.Image;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

But I cannot use the second code because I need to click a ContextMenuStrip to open Form2.

Any question write in comments!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768737/interaction-between-forms-how-to-change-a-control-of-a-form-from-another-form)

Comment: Also this duplicate: [How to access a form control for another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822980/how-to-access-a-form-control-for-another-form)

Comment: It's very different from PictureBox and images, I know how to do it with values, but I'm not sure I know with images. If you could answer this question with a solution it would be helpful!

Comment: A picture box is a specialized control. All patterns for accessing a control of another form from a form work, depending on the scenario and behavior.

Comment: A "*wild*" solution is to make forms as singleton. Personally, I create all my single instance forms as singleton so that I can do whatever I want, espacially with the form having a typed DataSet instance (there is no data module like in Delphi). Only temporary forms are conventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Form1, "Fr2" needs to be declared at Form level so you can access it from both "pictureBox1_MouseEnter" and "pictureBox2_Click".  Set the `Owner` by passing "this" to `Show()`.

This is for Form1:

```
private Form2 Fr2;

private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Fr2 = new Form2();
}

private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Fr2!=null && !Fr2.IsDisposed)
    {
        Fr2.Show(this); // <-- pass Form1 as the Owner
    }
}
```

This is for Form2:

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 Fr1 = this.Owner as Form1;
    if (Fr1!=null)
    {
        Fr1.pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox2.Image;
    }
}
```

To access "pictureBox1" in Form1, though, you'd have to change the `Modifiers` property of it to public.