# Changing text in one form, from another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Im trying to change the text in Form1 when pushing the button on Form2

Form 2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.textCh = "Text has been changed";
    }
}
```

Form 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public string textCh { 
        get
        {
            return this.textCh;
        }
        set
        {
            this.label1.Text = value;
        } 
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

When I'm pushing button nothing happens, the text remain the same.

[image: 1]

Comment: Add f1.Show() so you can see the changed text.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about that, but is there a way to update text in Form1 without opening a new window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a form control for another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822980/how-to-access-a-form-control-for-another-form)

Comment: Also this duplicate: [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768737/interaction-between-forms-how-to-change-a-control-of-a-form-from-another-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several way to do this here 2 examples

1. This example use references whitout any use of events

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();
    }

   }
   ```

here the `Form2` is created passing the `Form1` as parameter

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 _parent;
    public Form2(Form1 parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lbl = (Label)_parent.Controls.Find("label1", false).First();
        lbl.Text = "new text";
        _parent.Update();
    }
}
```

Than the `Form2` use that for set the value wanted.

2. This example use events

   ```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var frm = new Form2();
            frm.UpdateLabelEvent += Frm_UpdateLabelEvent;
            frm.Show();
        }

        private void Frm_UpdateLabelEvent(string str)
        {
            label1.Text = str;
        }
    }
   ```

and here the code of `Form2`

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public event Action<string> UpdateLabelEvent;
    
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateLabelEvent("new string value");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method of passing Form1 to Form2 via the `Show()` method and the `.Owner` property:

```
// In Form1
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog(this); // <-- pass Form1 via "this"
```

Then, in Form2, you CAST `.Owner` to type Form1:

```
// In Form2
Form1 f1 = this.Owner as Form1;
if (f1!=null && !f1.IsDisposed) 
{
    f1.textCh = "Text has been changed";
}
```

Comment: thanks you actually teach me something new that i didn't even know could exist :D

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changes in your Form1 because you are creating a new Form1 first and change the text there. The new Form1 is never shown, so you see no changes.

Solution

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Form1 f1 = new Form1(); GET rid of this line
    f1.textCh = "Text has been changed";
}
```

you need to make sure off course that f1 is known in form2, if you dont know how here is a simple way to do that

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.f1 = this;
    f2.ShowDialog();
}

public Form2()
{
    public Form1 f1 { get; set; }
    ...
```